# How to extract a particular text from a document using notepadd++ based on the input data

Tags: networking

Could someone please let me know the best way to do the following.

I need to extract the following fields:  `protocol=`    and   `dst_port=`    ,  my input to the file would be a list of IP addresses,  for eg.  `dst_ip=10.46.25.11`

So whenever `dst_ip=10.46.25.1`1, I want the script to extract `protocol=`  and   `dst_port=` fields.

Is this possible?

Below is a 2 line sample of my input log file. The log file has almost a million entries.

```
device="SFW" date=2023-06-21 time=12:52:48 timezone="AEST" device_name="XG310" device_id=C30055Q2CVGH6FC log_id=010101600001 log_type="Firewall" log_component="Firewall Rule" log_subtype="Allowed" status="Allow" priority=Information duration=194 fw_rule_id=195 policy_type=1 user_name="" user_gp="" iap=0 ips_policy_id=0 appfilter_policy_id=0 application="HTTP" application_risk=1 application_technology="Browser Based" application_category="General Internet" in_interface="ipsec0" out_interface="Port6.100" src_mac=00:00:00:00:00:00 src_ip=192.168.181.199 src_country_code=R1 dst_ip=10.46.25.11 dst_country_code=R1 protocol="TCP" src_port=57055 dst_port=80 sent_pkts=44  recv_pkts=155 sent_bytes=17289 recv_bytes=203819 tran_src_ip= tran_src_port=0 tran_dst_ip= tran_dst_port=0 srczonetype="VPN" srczone="VPN" dstzonetype="LAN" dstzone="LAN" dir_disp="" connevent="Stop" connid="2104534312" vconnid="" hb_health="No Heartbeat" message="" appresolvedby="Signature" app_is_cloud=0

device="SFW" date=2023-06-21 time=12:53:59 timezone="AEST" device_name="XG310" device_id=C30055Q2CVGH6FC log_id=010101600001 log_type="Firewall" log_component="Firewall Rule" log_subtype="Allowed" status="Allow" priority=Information duration=0 fw_rule_id=203 policy_type=1 user_name="" user_gp="" iap=0 ips_policy_id=0 appfilter_policy_id=0 application="" application_risk=0 application_technology="" application_category="" in_interface="Port1" out_interface="Port6.100" src_mac=00:00:00:00:00:00 src_ip=192.168.1.70 src_country_code=R1 dst_ip=10.46.25.11 dst_country_code=R1 protocol="TCP" src_port=53618 dst_port=80 sent_pkts=0  recv_pkts=0 sent_bytes=0 recv_bytes=0 tran_src_ip= tran_src_port=0 tran_dst_ip= tran_dst_port=0 srczonetype="LAN" srczone="LAN" dstzonetype="LAN" dstzone="LAN" dir_disp="" connevent="Start" connid="1778437568" vconnid="" hb_health="No Heartbeat" message="" appresolvedby="Signature" app_is_cloud=0
```

Comment: Please post your script

Comment: by script you mean my input file or you mean a py script? I am trying to use Notepad ++ .

Comment: Notepad++ can do one IP, with difficulty, but not a list of them. I suggest to find another tool.